# Can I set a multi-line environment variable in systemd's EnvironmentFile?

Tags: debian, systemd

I need an environment variable like this defined for my application's mail features to work:

```
RUBY_MAIL_SMTP_SETTINGS='
:address: "smtp.example.com"
:port: "25"
:authentication: :plain
:encryption: :tls
:user_name: "user"
:password: "pass"
'
```

Pasting that into a bash terminal works fine, but putting it into an environment file and referencing it from a systemd unit file with the `EnvironmentFile` option does not work:

```
juli 01 07:17:58 myserver systemd[1]: Ignoring invalid environment 'RUBY_MAIL_SMTP_SETTINGS=
juli 01 07:17:58 myserver systemd[1]: :address: "smtp.example.com"
juli 01 07:17:58 myserver systemd[1]: :port: "25"
juli 01 07:17:58 myserver systemd[1]: :authentication: :plain
juli 01 07:17:58 myserver systemd[1]: :encryption: :tls
juli 01 07:17:58 myserver systemd[1]: :user_name: "user"
juli 01 07:17:58 myserver systemd[1]: :password: "pass"': /usr/local/etc/myproject/environment
```

I have tried appending a backslash after each line, like this:

```
RUBY_MAIL_SMTP_SETTINGS='\
:address: "smtp.example.com"\
:port: "25"\
:authentication: :plain\
:encryption: :tls\
:user_name: "user"\
:password: "pass"
'
```

This works, but is interpreted as one long line, which means that the contents can't be parsed as YAML.

So does this mean it's impossible to add multi-lined environment variables to systemd environment files?

Comment: Typically each of these settings would have its own environment variable.

Comment: @MichaelHampton True, but I got lazy and wanted to minimize the amount of environment variables. I'll probably go back and implement config files, but at this point I would love to get this working.

Answer (score 5):

You need to quote whole variable assignment (not the value) AND backslash each line.

Example service file:

```
[Service]
Environment='RUBY_MAIL_SMTP_SETTINGS=\
:address: "smtp.example.com"\
:port: "25"\
:authentication: :plain\
:encryption: :tls\
:user_name: "user"\
:password: "pass"\
'

ExecStart=/bin/echo $RUBY_MAIL_SMTP_SETTINGS
```

Running this example will produce log:

```
Oct 27 14:03:32 io echo[9621]: :address: smtp.example.com :port: 25 :authentication: :plain :encryption: :tls :user_name: user :password: pass
```

Comment: Alas instead of newlines there are spaces in this output. Anyone who needs to pass in standard public/private keys via Systemd is going to be $hi* out of luck.

Comment: @rektide Exactly my problem. Do you know of any solution for this?

Comment: @rektide I haven't tested this, but [`\n` is apparently supported at least sometimes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.syntax.html#Quoting).